Problems in installing the latest edition of Texmaker [2]
Like in [1], I too am having problems in installing the latest edition of Texmaker
When I type
$ sudo dpkg -i texmaker_6.0.0_ubuntu_24_04_amd64.deb
Here is what happens
Preparing to unpack texmaker_6.0.0_ubuntu_24_04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking texmaker (6.0.0-1) over (6.0.0-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of texmaker:
 texmaker depends on libqt6core5compat6 (>= 6.2.1); however:
  Package libqt6core5compat6 is not installed.
 texmaker depends on libqt6core6t64 (>= 6.4.0); however:
  Package libqt6core6t64 is not installed.
 texmaker depends on libqt6gui6t64 (>= 6.4.0); however:
  Package libqt6gui6t64 is not installed.
 texmaker depends on libqt6network6t64 (>= 6.1.2); however:
  Package libqt6network6t64 is not installed.
 texmaker depends on libqt6printsupport6t64 (>= 6.1.2); however:
  Package libqt6printsupport6t64 is not installed.
 texmaker depends on libqt6qml6 (>= 6.2.0); however:
  Package libqt6qml6 is not installed.
 texmaker depends on libqt6webenginecore6 (>= 6.3.0); however:
  Package libqt6webenginecore6 is not installed.
 texmaker depends on libqt6webenginecore6-bin (>= 6.3.0); however:
  Package libqt6webenginecore6-bin is not installed.
 texmaker depends on libqt6webenginewidgets6 (>= 6.2.2); however:
  Package libqt6webenginewidgets6 is not installed.
 texmaker depends on libqt6widgets6t64 (>= 6.3.0); however:
  Package libqt6widgets6t64 is not installed.
 texmaker depends on libqt6xml6t64 (>= 6.1.2); however:
  Package libqt6xml6t64 is not installed.
 texmaker depends on qt6-base-abi (= 6.4.2); however:
  Package qt6-base-abi is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package texmaker (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.27-2build1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1.1ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 texmaker

Question
What do I do about this?
References
[1] Problems in installing the latest edition of Texmaker

Based on the errors you are getting, it seems that you have missing dependencies (a few QT libraries, for a start). You can try using apt rather than dpkg, which does dependency resolution, and will offer to install the required packages. Alternatively, you could install the collection of packages which dpkg is complaining about, and then try again.
List of packages the error message contains (may not be all of the dependencies):
libqt6core5compat6
libqt6core6t64
libqt6gui6t64
libqt6network6t64
libqt6printsupport6t64
libqt6qml6
libqt6webenginecore6
libqt6webenginecore6-bin
libqt6webenginewidgets6
libqt6widgets6t64
libqt6xml6t64
qt6-base-abi

EDIT in response to comment
apt can be used to install a local package (and all dependencies), but requires the command to identify that the package is local: sudo apt install ./texmaker_6.0.0_ubuntu_24_04_amd64.deb (note the ./ in front of the package name). This is generally the path I would recommend, since dpkg does no dependency resolution. If you want to get the list of dependencies that the .deb file has, you can use dpkg -I texmaker_6.0.0_ubuntu_24_04_amd64.deb, but be aware that these packages themselves may also have dependencies, which you will also need to find. All in all, using apt is much simpler, since it does all of this for you.
There is a reasonable explanation of how to check dependencies for a Debian/Ubuntu based Linux install here.

Hi. Can you offer some additional detail. How would I use apt to install?  How would I use dpkg to install the dependencies?

@MichaelLevy, I have updated the answer to include more explanations of how to use apt to install this package.
